# List Category Posts - thumbnails

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I'm trying to use the List Category Posts Plugin so that I can have different categories of posts show up at the bottom of different pages. I can't seem to get the thumbnails=yes option to work. It does display an image, but not thumbnail size.

Does anyone use this and know the answer to this problem?

Thanks
Betsy S. Franz
www.hbca-brevard.org

Comment: can you post a direct link to a page where the thumbs can be seen?

Answer (score 1):

The thumbnail size parameter was added to [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/) on version 0.19. You will now be able to use the `thumbnail_size` parameter and pass it either a string keyword (thumbnail, medium, large or full) or a 2-item array representing width and height in pixels, e.g. array(32,32) just like the native function.